# Python Property Problem which Converts Temperature from Fahrenheit to Celsius and Vice Versa

Tags: python, dependency-properties

Code :-

```
class Celsius:
    def __get__(self, obj, owner):
        return self.__fahrenheit
    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if not isinstance(value, int):
            raise TypeError("'fahrenheit' must be an integer.")
        self.__fahrenheit = value

class Temperature:
    fahrenheit = Celsius()
    celsius = 0.0
    def __init__(self,fahrenheit):
        self.fahrenheit = fahrenheit
        #Temperature.fahrenheit = Temperature.celsius + 32
        Temperature.celsius = float(self.fahrenheit - 32)

e1 = Temperature(78)
print(e1.fahrenheit, e1.celsius)
e1.celsius = 2.0
print(e1.fahrenheit, e1.celsius)
```

Output :-
78 46.0
78 2.0

I want e1.fahrenheit value to be 34 when e1.celsius = 2.0, but don't want to add any more methods or classes.

Comment: Please format the code - select it and type `ctrl-k`.
.. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: My understanding is that OP wants the `fahrenheit` attribute to change after assigning the celsius attribute `e1.celsius = 2.0`. This can be done through setter methods (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/getter-and-setter-in-python/). He is not going to meet his constraint of adding no additional methods however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Celsius:

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return 5 * (instance.fahrenheit - 32) / 9

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        instance.fahrenheit = 32 + 9 * value / 5


class Temperature:

    celsius = Celsius()

    def __init__(self, initial_f):
        self.fahrenheit = initial_f


e1 = Temperature(32)
print(e1.fahrenheit, e1.celsius)
e1.celsius = 0.0
print(e1.fahrenheit, e1.celsius)
```

Output:

```
32, 0.0
32.0 0.0
```

Got my perfect solution, using 'instance' object

Comment: Please take a moment to learn the code formatting tools here - they are very easy to use, and will make your posts much more readable.